# jquery validate conflict with toggle function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i try to validate my simple form using jquery validate and inside my form i have one checkbox when user click, it will toggle tr and show extra input field.

But now i cannot validate my form unless i remove the toggle checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="popup('#item1','.box1')" id="item1" />Tick to show
```

, below is my toggle function :

```
function popup(checkbox, box){
     $(checkbox).change(function() {                
     $(box).toggle(this.checked); //if checkbox checked show div
  }).change(); //ensure visible state matches initially
};
```

and you can check my [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/2TfB2/5/)

*yes i also try using jQuery.noConflict(); but the result still same*

Comment: its ok .. problem solved

Comment: You can post the answer then mark it as the selected answer when the time is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when we implement jquery validation using **jquery.validate.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

all input type must have `name` including `type="button"` to avoid jquery conflict, even the input type just to trigger some function.

Comment: this is true, but your fiddle was bombing out because your checkbox didn't have a name